# How can I delete a row in a table by 'onclick' on a button that is dynamically generated within the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I made a table that is dynamically generated.
I must have a button in the last column of each line that as soon as I click it two things will happen:

1. The entire line will be marked with `<strike>`
2. The ID of the row will go into a special array.

The last td in each row is a button from a class called `trash_button` to which a jQuery function is linked that should cause each button from that class to add to its row a section called `strikethrough`

The problem is that the buttons I tried to make just don't work.
Even though the function is linked to their class, from tests I did, it turns out that pressing the button does not even call the function.

I really can not understand what is wrong here.

```js
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
  var animals = [{
      "animalId": "1",
      "animalName": "elephent",
      "cageNum": "231",
      "legsNum": "4"
    },
    {
      "animalId": "2",
      "animalName": "tiger",
      "cageNum": "324",
      "legsNum": "56.00"
    },
    {
      "animalId": "3",
      "animalName": "wolf",
      "cageNum": "414",
      "legsNum": "210.40"
    }
  ]
  
  var tableBody = '<table id="table"><tr class="tr tr1"><td class="td1">animal Id</td><td class="td1">animal name</td><td class="td1">cage Number</td><td class="td1">legs Number</td><td class="td1">delete</td></tr>';

  animals.forEach(function(d) {
     tableBody += '<tr class="tr tr2"><td class="td2">'+d.animalId
     +'</td><td class="td2">' +d.animalName
      +'</td><td class="td2">'+d.cageNum
      +'</td><td class="td2">'+d.legsNum
      +'</td><td class="td2"><input type="button" class="trash_button"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/24" width="100%" height="100%"></input></td></tr>';
  });

  var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
  divContainer.innerHTML = tableBody;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".trash_button").on('click', function() {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

    if (document.getElementById(currentRow.id).classList.contains('strikethrough')) {
      document.getElementById(currentRow.id).classList.remove('strikethrough');
    } else {
      document.getElementById(currentRow.id).classList.add('strikethrough');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON">animal table</button>

<div id="showData">(Div added by community)</div>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Where is the element with ID `showData`?

Comment: I've added the container element to the snippet. Please revise further to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding markup dynamically you need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to catch the clicks on the buttons as they bubble up the DOM. You should also stick with either jQuery or vanilla JS. This example uses vanilla JS.

```js
function createTable(div, data) {

  let tableBody = '<table id="table"><tr class="tr tr1"><td class="td1">animal Id</td><td class="td1">animal name</td><td class="td1">cage Number</td><td class="td1">legs Number</td><td class="td1"></td></tr>';

  const deleteBtn = "https://dummyimage.com/80x20/FFA07A/000&text=Delete";

  animals.forEach(function(d) {
    tableBody += `
      <tr class="tr tr2">
        <td class="td2">${d.animalId}</td>
        <td class="td2">${d.animalName}</td>
        <td class="td2">${d.cageNum}</td>
        <td class="td2">${d.legsNum}</td>
        <td class="td2 delete">
          <img class="trash_button" src="${deleteBtn}" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    `;
  });

  showData.innerHTML = tableBody;

}

const animals = [{
    "animalId": "1",
    "animalName": "elephent",
    "cageNum": "231",
    "legsNum": "4"
  },
  {
    "animalId": "2",
    "animalName": "tiger",
    "cageNum": "324",
    "legsNum": "56.00"
  },
  {
    "animalId": "3",
    "animalName": "wolf",
    "cageNum": "414",
    "legsNum": "210.40"
  }
];

const button = document.querySelector('.createTable');
const showData = document.querySelector('.showData');

button.addEventListener('click', () => createTable(showData, animals));

showData.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.trash_button')) {
    e.target.closest('tr').classList.toggle('strikethrough');
  }
}
```

```css
table { margin-top: 2em; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
td { padding: 0.3em; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; }
.tr1 { font-size: 0.8em; background-color: #efefef; text-transform: uppercase; }
.strikethrough { text-decoration: line-through; }
.createTable:hover, .delete:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<button class="createTable">Animal table</button>
<table class="showData"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the id and data attributes to specifically target each element:

```
animals.forEach( function(animal) {
  //I've shortened for brevity, note I'm also using backticks to use js literal syntax
  tableBody += `<tr class="tr" id="animal-${animal.animalId}">
                  <td>${animal.animalName}</td>
                  <td><button class="trash_button" data-id="${animal.animalId}">Delete</button>
                </tr>`
});


......

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.trash_button').on('click', function(button) {
    let id = button.data.id;
    $(`#animal-${id}`).toggleClass('strikethrough');
  });
});
```